# Raspberry Pi project - no module named error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Ok so im trying my first Raspberry Pi project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2QFu-tTvTI

i have followed the steps for installing open cv and the other dependencies but when i try to run it i get the following error

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Smart-Security-Camera $ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mail import sendEmail
  File "/home/pi/Smart-Security-Camera/mail.py", line 2, in <module>
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
ImportError: No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart'
```

i then tried entering "sudo python main.py" and got a different messege but the same problem as shown below

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Smart-Security-Camera $ sudo python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from camera import VideoCamera
  File "/home/pi/Smart-Security-Camera/camera.py", line 2, in <module>
    from imutils.video.pivideostream import PiVideoStream
ImportError: No module named imutils.video.pivideostream
```

finally i tried "sudo python3 main.py" and again different messege same issue.

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Smart-Security-Camera $ sudo python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: you will have to get the module installed on the pi before calling the code, I am guessing on raspi, you still use pip

Comment: I installed the opencv before I cloned the repo I'm so lost lol